# How to escape quotes in bash array elements

Tags: arrays, bash, escaping, quotes

I want to create an array like so

```
array=(

"element1 with "quoted string""
"element2 without double quoted string"
"element3"
)
```

After running the code it outputs

```
echo ${array[0]}                                                               
element1 with quoted.
```

I'm trying to include the quotes in the echo'd output. How do I do this?

Comment: You should also put double-quotes around the variable (/array) reference when you use it, e.g. `echo "${array[0]}"` instead of just `echo ${array[0]} `. This will not affect double-quotes in the string value, but will avoid trouble with some other shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

Either use single quotes,

```
array=(
'element1 with "quoted string"'
...
)
```

or escape the literal double quotes:

```
array=(
"element1 with \"quoted string\""
...
)
```

Your first nested quote closes the opening quote, but `quoted` still considered part of the current word. The next element of the array is `string` with an empty string appended to its end.